# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition; Exception encountered while running Spring4.x and Hibernate 4.x Webapp

Tags: spring, hibernate

-- I am trying to run a Spring 4.x, Hibernate 4.x web application with Tomcat7 and Java 8 in Eclipse Mars IDE.
This is a basic webapp which will insert values in SQL database using SpringMVC, Hibernate and Maven.

-- While starting tomcat I am getting the exception :Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [Lorg/hibernate/engine/FilterDefinition.

-- I tried searching online for the solution and found the configuration to be done to resolve this exception which is already there in my code.
The solution says to use the below configuration in dispatcher-servlet xml file for sessionFactory and transactionManger.

1. `<bean id="sessionFactory"
           class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">`
2. `<bean id="transactionManager"              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">`

-- To check if its a jar compatibility issue did hit and trial with lot many combination of Spring4 and Hibernate4 versions, like Hibernate Version as : 4.3.5.Final and Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE.

-- As its giving NoClassDefFoundError I checked in Hibernate-Core jar. The FilterDefinition class is unavailable at the mentioned path and its available in `hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.zip\org\hibernate\engine\spi` path. So probably this exception is coming.

-- Kindly let me know how to avoid this exception.

```
pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MavenWeb</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenWeb</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
<java.version>1.6</java.version>

<org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>

<hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>

<slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Logging with SLF4J-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>




        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


<!-- for compilation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<!-- jstl dependency -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question and provide more info about the problem, source code, configuration etc.

Comment: Have rephrased the question , hope its bit clearer now. Kindly revert with solution or more info required about the code.

Comment: Kindly give some pointers to avoid this exception With Spring3 and Hibernate3, this particular exception is not coming.

Comment: Are you using maven? then please post the `pom.xml` file. It looks like a jar conflict. Do you perform clean before building your project?

Comment: yes I am using Maven. have attached my current pom.xml where I have chnaged the Spring and Hibernate Versions and I am not getting the class not found exception for Filter Definition but now i am getting new exception: org.springframework.web.servlet.dispatcherservlet class not found exception.  For this I found solution that I need to add some stuff in deployment assembly of my project. But I cannot find relavant things in my project's deployment assembly to be added. I cannot attach snap of the same as I dnt have enough points on stackoverflow to do the same. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: From `pom.xml` it is obvious that you are not using Hibernate4 (4.3.5.Final) as you stated....see: `<hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>` so adjust your `dispatcher-servlet.xml` accordingly

Comment: Yes u are correct, I have changed the version of spring and hibernate to get rid of the above exception. But now as said I am facing other exception,

Comment: In short, with <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>

<hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>, getting  Class not found exception for Dispatcher Servlet. With Hibernate Version : 4.3.5.Final and Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE, getting Class Not found Exception for FilterDefinition

Comment: post your `web.xml` and `dispatcher-servlet.xml` files